# Extracting Comments from Version History in Powershell

Tags: 2010, powershell, version-comments

So I am trying to extract version history from a document library in Powershell. I have found the commands/scripts to do this. However I cannot seem to get the comments.
From my script I can get modified date ($Ver.Created), user ($Ver.CreatedBy), and version ($Ver.VersionLabel) where $Ver is derived from the foreachloop that loops through Items in a Document Library.

I checked Microsoft's Object members site and found 'Comments', but this has produced nothing.
I have tried "Comment", "CheckedInComments", "CheckedInComment".

At this point I am trying to find the script that will extract all member names so I can see which one it is. And yes I do have comments there.

The internet has helped. It helped me make the script I have so far but it looks like all the examples I have found do not talk about the comments at all.

----Update-----
I found the member, altering the script to look like this:

> $Ver["Check In Comment"]

Instead of this:

> $Ver.CheckInComment

I get results but its only the last comment of the latest version. The object gets me different data ("VersionLabel") except for the comments

```
foreach ($item in $ItemsColl)  
{
    if ($item.Name -eq $fileName)
    {
    Write-Output "File Name " $item.Name | Out-File $logFile -append
        foreach($Ver in $item.Versions)
        {
            Write-Output "Version Label" $Ver.VersionLabel " Created " $Ver.Created " Modified by " $Ver.CreatedBy.User.DisplayName | Out-File $logFile -append
            Write-Output "Check In Comment " $Ver["Check In Comment"] | Out-File $logFile -append
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are iterating through the version history for the list item itself but it sounds like what you want is the information for the file versions which is a little deeper.  There is a `.File` property off of the SPListItem that returns an SPFile object.  That object has a Versions collection that you need to iterate through to get [the information you want](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfileversion.checkincomment).

Comment: That makes sense ... Will work on that.